# Error 7: Out of memory when assigning array to range

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a procedure that assigns formulas to an array. Then I want to insert those formulas into the sheet. But when the code line that assigns the values of the array to a range in the sheet is executed, an error is thrown.
Here's the code:

```
Public Sub createDropDownListValidationWithSearchForCell(targetCell As Range, startingCellOfCalculations As Range, listToGetValuesFrom As Range)
Dim calculations() As Variant
ReDim calculations(1 To UBound(listToGetValuesFrom.Value2), 1 To 3)
Dim secondCLetter As String
Dim listToGetValuesFromCLetter As String
listToGetValuesFromCLetter = Col_Letter(listToGetValuesFrom.Column)
secondCLetter = Col_Letter(startingCellOfCalculations.Column)
For counter = 1 To UBound(calculations)
    calculations(counter, 1) = "=SE(ÉERRO(LOCALIZAR(" & targetCell.Address & ";" & listToGetValuesFrom(counter, 1).Address(External:=True) & "));0;1)"
    calculations(counter, 2) = "=SE(" & startingCellOfCalculations.Offset(counter - 1, 0).Address & "=0;" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ";CONT.SE(" & startingCellOfCalculations.Address & ":" & startingCellOfCalculations.Offset(counter - 1, 0).Address & ";1))"
    calculations(counter, 3) = "=SEERRO(ÍNDICE('" & Split(listToGetValuesFrom.Address(External:=True), "$")(0) & listToGetValuesFromCLetter & ":" & listToGetValuesFromCLetter & ";CORRESP(LIN(" & startingCellOfCalculations.Offset(counter - 2, 1).Address & ");" & secondCLetter & secondCLetter & ";0));" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
Next counter
startingCellOfCalculations.Resize(UBound(calculations), 3).FormulaLocal = calculations
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you want `listToGetValuesFrom.rows.count` in place of this, `UBound(listToGetValuesFrom.Value2)`

Comment: Is it the last line `startingCellOfCalculations.Resize()..` raising the error ?

Comment: Yes @CDP1802, it's that line.

Comment: How many rows in the range `listToGetValuesFrom` ?

Comment: @CDP1802 46 rows.

Comment: Try `Resize(UBound(calculations), 3)` with 1,2 then 3 in turn.

Comment: Sorry´@CDP1802, I didn't understand what you mean. 1,2 and 3 where? Can you explain it with other words?